# Create post controller works with image (file) but not without image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, multer

I'm having trouble with my controller Post to create a post.

I think the main problem is that the condition "if (req.file !== null)" is still working same if i'm not uploading a file (**The picture field** to be accurate because picture is supposed to be a file)

If someone already had this problem I would like to hear it ! Thank you by advance.

I will show you my code here :

post.controller.js (createPost only)

```js
module.exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  let fileName;

  if (req.file !== null) {
    try {
      if (
        req.file.mimetype != "image/jpg" &&
        req.file.mimetype != "image/png" &&
        req.file.mimetype != "image/jpeg"
      )
        throw Error("invalid file");
  
      if (req.file.size > 500000) throw Error("max size");
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = uploadErrors(err);
      return res.status(201).json({ errors });
    }
    fileName = req.body.posterId + Date.now() + ".jpg";

    try {
    await sharp(req.file.buffer)
    .resize({ width: 150, height: 150 }) 
    .toFile(`${__dirname}/../client/public/uploads/posts/${fileName}`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
  }

  const newPost = new postModel({
    posterId: req.body.posterId,
    message: req.body.message,
    picture: req.file !== null ? "./uploads/posts/" + fileName : "",
    video: req.body.video,
    likers: [],
    comments: [],
  });

  try {
    const post = await newPost.save();
    return res.status(201).json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err);
  }
};
```

post.routes.js :

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const postController = require('../controllers/post.controller');
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();

router.get('/', postController.readPost);
router.post('/', upload.single("file"), postController.createPost);
```

postModel :

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    posterId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      maxlength: 500,
    },
    picture: {
      type: String,
    },
    video: {
      type: String,
    },
    likers: {
      type: [String],
      // required: true,
    },
    comments: {
      type: [
        {
          commenterId:String,
          commenterPseudo: String,
          text: String,
          timestamp: Number,
        }
      ],
      // required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you don't upload image, the `req.file` will be **undefined**, and NOT **null**.

Try to change your code from this:

```js
if (req.file !== null) {
```

to this:

```js
if (req.file) {
```